# Best way to visualize this data?

Tags: python, matplotlib, data-analysis

I have 3 dataset that looks something like this but with around 600 records.

```
[440.2, 441.5, 440.9, 441.8, 441.1 ..............]
[722.3, 722.8, 722.1, 723.0, 722.7 ..............] 
[817.2, 817.6, 818.0, 817.5, 817.9 ..............]
```

The values within the dataset are very close to each other while far away from others. How to plot such kind of data such that all of the datapoints are in one graph to show comparison?

Answer (score 1):

This generally depends on what comparison you do want to make, but my suggestion is to use a 3-series scatter plot for your 3 arrays, alongside an incremental index. Typically, your graph would be something like this where x is the 1st array, y is the 2nd array and z is the 3rd array:

[image]

You can see here that X has a tendency to be on the lower spectrum. Y in the middle between 500 and 750 and finally z at the upper spectrum.

This is how your data should look like in the table (Add the index).
[image]